# How do I solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+5$ with $x(0)=-3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How do I solve differential equation 
>   $$
> \frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+5
> $$ if the beginning value is $x(0)=-3$?

---

What I have done:

$$\frac{dt}{dx}=x^2+5$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+5}=\int dt$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+5}=\frac{tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

So I use that $u=(1+\frac{x}{5})$. Then I get:

$$1+\frac{x}{5}=e^{-5t}C$$

$$x=\frac{5}{e^{-5t}C-1}$$

So I get then that $C$ is $8$. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: How about writing $\displaystyle \int dy = \int (x^2 + 5)~dx$?

Comment: How did you get $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+5}$?  You divided $x^2+5$ to the left side, but somehow you magically flip the $dx$ to the numerator?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer. @Moo

Comment: $\int\frac a{x^2+a^2}dx=\arctan(x/a)+c$  should be a known integral.

Comment: Are you using multiple accounts to ask homework questions? There have been two rather similar questions posted by users with almost identical usernames...

Comment: No, I don't use it. I have friends. @Ian

Comment: Please read my question @amWhy

Comment: Sorry, but it's not dt/dx, it's dx/dt ;) @amWhy

Comment: Is it $\frac {dx}{dt} = x^2 + 5$, as in your title, or is it $\frac {dt}{dx} = x^2 + 5$? as in the first line of your attempt? Whatever the case, you've already wasted a lot of user's time because of your edit, and your flip-flopping between dx/dt and dt/dx...and your dismissal of comments. I'm done here.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you thought.

If $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x^2+5$ then, integrating in both terms, we have
$$ y(x)=\int (x^2+5) dx$$

Comment: I corrected my question @rdias

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the *initial value* problem:

> $$
> \frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+5,\quad x(0)=-3.
> $$

You got 
$$
\frac{dx}{x^2+5}=dt.
$$
Do you know what to get

$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2+5}\ dx?
$$

Your calculation is wrong about this integral. Try a simpler one:
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx
$$
and then try to see how you can use change of variables to get the previous one.

Comment: $\frac{tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5}}$ any more simple way?

Comment: No, but, $\arctan (0) = 0$. So, your initial condition makes it easy to solve for your constant of integration.